# Jersey JAXB Based JSON support

Tags: json, jaxb, jersey, jboss7.x

I am trying to use Jersey's capabilities to produce JSON from my web-service methods.
Everything worked well but then I discovered that for a list of objects JSON representation contains something like enclosing root tag. I found out that I can configure JAXB Based JSON support with JSONConfiguration.natural() to produce a desirable result. So I wrote the following

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {

    private final JAXBContext context;

    private final Set<Class> types;

    private final Class[] cTypes = {TrRegion.class};

    public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {
        this.types = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(cTypes));
        this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().build(), cTypes);
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> objectType) {
        return (types.contains(objectType)) ? context : null;
    }
}
```

And plugged it in like this

```
public class WebServiceApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses()
    {
        Set<Class<?>> resources = new HashSet<Class<?>>();

        resources.add(OrderInfrastructureResource.class);
        resources.add(OrderResource.class);

        resources.add(JAXBContextResolver.class);

        return resources;
    }
}

  <servlet>
    <description>JAX-RS Tools Generated - Do not modify</description>
    <servlet-name>JAX-RS Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>javax.ws.rs.Application</param-name>
        <param-value>com.[...].WebServiceApplication</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
```

But for some reason I always get

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JAXB provider found for the following JAXB context: class com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl
    at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.JSONHelper.getJaxbProvider(JSONHelper.java:106) [jersey-json-1.17.jar:1.17]    
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.JSONHelper.getJaxbProvider(JSONHelper.java:106) [jersey-json-1.17.jar:1.17]
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.DefaultJaxbXmlDocumentStructure.getXmlDocumentStructure(DefaultJaxbXmlDocumentStructure.java:76) [jersey-json-1.17.jar:1.17]
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.writer.Stax2JacksonWriter.<init>(Stax2JacksonWriter.java:169) [jersey-json-1.17.jar:1.17]
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.Stax2JsonFactory.createWriter(Stax2JsonFactory.java:105) [jersey-json-1.17.jar:1.17]
at com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider.writeList(JSONListElementProvider.java:133) [jersey-json-1.17.jar:1.17]
```

Can someone tell me why?

When I change the line

```
this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.natural().build(), cTypes);
```

to

```
this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(JSONConfiguration.mapped().build(), cTypes);
```

it begins to work but gives enclosing root tag(well it is the same as not specifying any ContextResolver). Strange.(Strange meaning, that the difference is only in mapping type I provide).

I try to run my app on Jboss 7.1.1 with Restesy disabled(I have removed lines `<extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>` and `<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>` from my standalone.xml file). Also I use com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet as Jersey servlet.

Please, tell me what am I missing.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was missing jaxb-impl library for my application so I just added jBoss' `com.sun.xml.bind` module in my jboss-deployment-structure file as following:

```
<dependencies>
  <module name="com.sun.xml.bind" />
  <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-core-asl" />
  <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-jaxrs" />
  <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-mapper-asl" />
  <module name="org.codehaus.jackson.jackson-xc" />
</dependencies>
```